# Integrate GRPC server with Rails codebase

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, protocol-buffers, grpc

When the Google::Protobuf::DescriptorPool.generated_pool.build is called twice with the same message types, the error is being thrown saying that DescriptorPool has already registered message with the same name.

```
Unable to add defs to DescriptorPool: Symtab already has a def named
```

I see that as expected behavior.

Though, I need to include GRPC generated files within Rails codebase which some parts are eagerly loaded.

Is there any possible way to tell protobuf to generate Ruby classes and modules instead of generating `Google::Protobuf::DescriptorPool.generated_pool.build` block? In case it has generated classes, the require on that file more than once wouldn't throw an error.

I see the only way to fix this is to add some condition before `Google::Protobuf::DescriptorPool.generated_pool.build` block, letting it register messages unless these are already defined.

BTW I wanted to run gprc server within a rake task when I stumbled upon this issue.

Please tell me if I am missing something, which is quite likely. Thank you